# onActivityforResult is not triggered/called

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, onactivityresult

I have Activity A and B. When I'm on Activity B and some action is triggered I'm calling Activity A. On Activity B I'm using startActivityforResult, checking request code on activity result and showing alert dialog box on UI after Activity A is called. But my `onActivityresult` is not called and hence my dialog box.

> Below is my code snippet.

```
 public void Logout() {
        autoLogoutHandler.removeMessages(MSG_APP_LOGOUT);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_B.this,
                Activity_A.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivityForResult(intent, OPEN_NEW_ACTIVITY);
    }
```

> And my onActivityResult I'm checking my request code, but it never
>   called.

```
    @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == OPEN_NEW_ACTIVITY) {
                alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getBaseContext())
                        .setTitle(null)
                        .setMessage(getString(xxxx))
                        .setIcon(null)
                        .setPositiveButton(getString(xxxx), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {


                            }
                        }).show();
            }
    }
```

Can someone help me out why my `onActivityResult` is not called?

Comment: Is your `onActivityResult` on ActivityB or ActivityA ?

Comment: Its on Activity B.

Comment: Why do you use `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`? Is ActivityA initiated before ActivityB at some point?

Comment: yes. ActivityA(login screen) is in the landing screen of my app. then activityB is launched.

Answer (score 0):

Your flows currently is

`A -> opens -> B -> start onActivityResult -> A   // doesn't work`

What you should do instead:

`A- > start onActivityResult -> B -> setResult() & finish() -> A -> handles onActivityResult -> voila!`

Activity A call & wait for activity B, after this activity process is information it will then need to return whether the result of the operation was a success `RESULT_OK` or failed/canceled `RESULT_CANCELED`.

After the activity B closes, the Activity A will perform the `onActivityResult` method, and as best practice, you will check which requestCode was called from the `startActivityForResult` and then check whether the operation was successfull or not...

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == 1) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // do work if successful
    }
}
...
```

Undestanding onActivityResult as per documentation:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: This is how i call my Activity_B. When I'm on Activity_B i have different fragments in it .. From one of the frag I'm logging out of the app to Activity_A(login screen). I don't want to use startacitivityForResult when I'm going from Activity_A to Activity_B as there is not result check.

public void Activity_B() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_A, Activity_B.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("tabIndex", 0);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

Comment: The startActivity on that method should be replaced by `startActivityForResult(intent, code)`

Comment: So you want me to put my UI i.e alert dialog in activity_A?